how to follow up on responses from individuals?
I am a newbie here.  I asked a question a while back and got some immediate responses that lead me to more questions.  Now I am stuck with my problem unsolved.  Is it possible to message some of the individuals who responded to my post, but by direct message?

Any way to send a personal message to another user? was asked 15 years ago for a direct feature request, but that is "status-declined". See also How do I contact other users?

This has been requested in the past over 15 years ago1 but was rejected a long time ago.
The only way to contact users directly would be to attempt to ping them with comments. Unfortunately, there's no way to directly contact those individuals within the site's mechanisms.
You may want to read this: How do I contact other users?
